# create next app > npm run dev > error "Command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js, windows-11

Yesterday, after running `npx create-next-app@latest` then `npm run dev` I receive an error `Command failed with exit code 1.` and `https://localhost:3000` displays an error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

```
Additional information
    Operating System:
      Platform: win32
      Arch: ia32
      Version: Windows 11 Home
    Binaries:
      Node: 18.16.0
      npm: 9.5.1
      Yarn: 1.22.19
      pnpm: N/A
    Relevant packages:
      next: 13.3.0
      eslint-config-next: 13.3.0
      react: 18.2.0
      react-dom: 18.2.0
```

The project directory does not have any spaces in it.

Today, in the same project directory `npm run dev` produces no errors but the terminal process does not stay running, it ends, and the terminal is back at the prompt again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `node -p 'process.arch'` produces `ia32`. My laptop is `Intel 64-bit`.

I uninstalled the current node, downloaded and installed `node-v18.16.0-x64`.

Now `node -p 'process.arch'` gives `x64`, and `npm run dev` builds the local client and server successfully at `http://localhost:3000`.

[HT to icyJoseph](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48472#discussioncomment-5649501).

Answer (score 0):

**Description**
I had the same problem
I created the app via `npx create-next-app@latest` (nextjs 13.4), when I tried to run it locally via `npm run dev` it gave a canvas of text and exit with error 1

**Solution**
Turns out I was running node 14.18.2 version, switched to version 18.14.0 and everything worked:

- `node -v`: check the current version of node
- `nvm ls`: list installed versions of node
- `nvm install 18.14.0`: install node version
  18.14.0 if it doesn't exist
- `nvm use 18.14.0`: switch to this version of node

**Check**
`npm run dev` runs the application on nextjs 13